# Convergence of $e^{X_n} / n$ if $X_n$ is $L^1$-bounded

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots$ be a sequence of real-valued random variables with $\sup_n \mathbb E(|X_n|) < \infty$.

**Question:** Does this imply
$$
\mathbb P\bigg[\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac 1 n \exp(X_n) = 0\bigg] = 1?
$$

**What I have tried:** At least, along a subsequence, this is clear since we have
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbb E\bigg(\frac {X_n} {\ln(n)}\bigg) = 0,
$$
which implies that there is a subsequence $X_{n_1}, X_{n_2},\ldots$ such that, $\mathbb P$-a.s.,
$$
\lim_{k\to \infty} \frac 1 {n_k} \exp(X_{n_k})
\\=
\lim_{k\to \infty} \exp (X_{n_k} - \ln(n_k))
\\=
\lim_{k\to \infty} \exp\bigg( \bigg(\underbrace{\frac {X_{n_k}} {\ln(n_k)}}_{\to 0} - 1 \bigg) \underbrace{\ln(n_k)}_{\to \infty} \bigg)
\\=
0
$$
However, we have not used yet that $\mathbb E(|X_n|)$ is bounded, but only a weaker implication of that instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convergence in probability holds but almost sure convergence need not hold. For a counter-example let $(X_n)$ be i.i.d  with exp(1) distribution. Then $P(\frac 1 n e^{X_n} >1)=P(X_n >\ln n)=e^{-\ln n}=\frac 1 n$. So $\sum_n P(\frac 1 n e^{X_n} >1)=\infty$ and Borel Cantelli Lemma show that $P(\lim \sup (\frac 1 n e^{X_n} >1))=1$. Hence, $\frac 1 n e^{X_n}$ does not tend to $0$ with probability $1$.